# How to use useContext inside a component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-context, use-context

I have a context that I have defined as 'HeaderContext' - I know its getting my data correctly becuase I can see the data in the console.log(headerData.Menu.PageUrl) line.

However I only see that when I uncomment the line and save the file after the page has loaded, so I suspect that the problem is that the data is not avalible when the page first loads. - This is my first react project so I think I'm missing something fundamental about what react is doing here.

Here is my code so far:

```
function Header() {

const [headerData] = useContext(HeaderContext)

console.log("heder data");
console.log(headerData.Menu.PageUrl);


return (
    <nav>
        <Link to="/">Logo here</Link>
        <ul>
            <li><Link to={headerData.Menu.PageUrl}>Menu</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
)}export default Header;
```

The error that I get is:

```
index.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PageUrl')
```

For clarity here is the HeaderContext:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import API from "../../API"
export const HeaderContext = createContext();
export const HeaderProvider = (props) => {

    const [headerData, setHeaderData] = useState([]);

    const getHeader = async () => {
        const header = await API.fetchHeader();
        setHeaderData(header);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getHeader();
    }, []);

    return (
        <HeaderContext.Provider value={[headerData]}>
            {props.children}
        </HeaderContext.Provider >
    );}
```

And here is the App.js file:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <MenuProvider>
            <div className="App">
                <HeaderProvider>
                    <Header />
                </HeaderProvider>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
                    <Route path="/menu/:id" element={<Category />} />
                    <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
                    <Route path="/more/faqs" element={<Faqs />} />
                    {/*<Home />*/}
                </Routes>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </MenuProvider>
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add all relevant code you've an issue working with. Can you share your header context code?

Comment: @DrewReese Question has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial `headerData` value is an empty array:

```
const [headerData, setHeaderData] = useState([]);
```

and passed in the context value also within an array:

```
<HeaderContext.Provider value={[headerData]}>
    {props.children}
</HeaderContext.Provider>
```

but you are accessing `headerData` value as if it were an object

```
console.log(headerData.Menu.PageUrl);
```

Since you say this works on subsequent renders it leads me to believe that `headerData` ***is actually*** really an object. Your Postman response confirms this.

The issue you have is that since `headerData` is an array the `Menu` property is undefined. This is ok until you try to access the `PageUrl` property of an undefined object.

Fix the initial `headerData` state value to also be an object:

```
const [headerData, setHeaderData] = useState({});
```

You might want to also pass it to the Context value as an object:

```
<HeaderContext.Provider value={headerData}>
    {props.children}
</HeaderContext.Provider>
```

Then just return it from the hook:

```
const headerData = useContext(HeaderContext);
```

and from here you'll just need to use Optional Chaining or null-checks/guard clauses to access into potentially undefined properties.

Examples:

- `headerData.Menu?.PageUrl`
- `headerData.Menu && headerData.Menu.PageUrl`

Comment: This makes ALOT of sense and thank you for making a few things clear here for me. However Making those changes around useState({}); and useState([]); then updating the console.log to headerData.Menu?.PageUrl results in the page loading correctly every single time great. HOWEVER when I try and output headerData.Menu?.PageUrl in to the link. I get another error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')" do I need to useEffect?

Comment: @AyoAdesina Oh, yeah, the `Link` component needs a defined `to` prop. You can either provide a fallback value, i.e. `<Link to={headerData.Menu?.PageUrl || "/menu"}>Menu</Link>`, or conditionally render the link when you have a defined destination, i.e. `{headerData.Menu?.PageUrl && <Link to={headerData.Menu.PageUrl}>Menu</Link>}`. Does this make sense? You may want to just conditionally render the entire header UI instead.

Comment: Having a fall back seems to work, even if I put in an empty string like this:
<li><Link to={headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl || ""}>Menu</Link></li>
I end up with the correct value ie "/menu" I guess that happens when the data gets loaded on the second rerender... HOWEVER this seems all very messy. Is there away I can make the page wait untill the data is avalible BEFORE trying to out put the values. All of these ? and && makes the code look YUKKY lol

Comment: @AyoAdesina Agree to disagree, I think it makes the code beautiful and easy to use. Like I said, the alternative would be to conditionally render the entire header UI. You could start with undefined or `null` `headerData` state, so a simple ternary would suffice, i.e. `return headerData ? (<nav> ..... </nav>) : null;`.

Comment: I know you shouldn't use comments to say thank you, but I what to say thanks :-) You have brought clarity to a few things for me here. But yes I think we will agree to disagree on that last point I will use this for now untill I learn a bit more about react and refactor later. Thank you a great comprehensive answer.

Comment: After reviewing some of my other code and examples I have been doing, I have a question/comment I would like to know what you think. Am I using the wrong approach, in terms of using the context api here, should I just call my api fuction from inside the component? would that change the way this works? and mean I don't need to provide this fall back value?

Comment: @AyoAdesina For very simple apps with minimal state, using a React context may be a bit overkill, but isn't an invalid use. The React Context API exists namely to eliminate the issue of "props drilling", that is to say, the issue created when you pass props from some component A to B, then from B to C, and then from C to D that *actually* cares and uses them. As your app and state grows in complexity, you'll want the benefit and simplicity of the Context. For example `react-redux` is an abstraction built over the Context API.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
   const getHeader = async () => {
        const header = await API.fetchHeader();
        setHeaderData(header);
    };
```

You are setting the `headerData` asynchronously and then pass it as value of the context provider. So the data is set later, when the fetchHeader is done. Basically you are first passing an empty array, then later when the async operation is done, you are setting it as an object I guess (I am not sure what the API returns).

Check this out to see how to use an async function in `useEffect` hook: https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect

Answer (score 0):

usually context api return values in **object** however you are saying that you getting data correctly.
your error is saying the data you trying to access is **undefind** acctualy the object property is **undefind** at the moment.
**you can access data like this:**

```
<li><Link to={headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl}>Menu</Link></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

*1st Solution:*
use optional chaining, that helps you to ignore the **headerData** attributes when they are undefined or null.

```
<li><Link to={headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl}>Menu</Link></li>
```

or *2nd Solution:*
you can set the initial keys of your **headerData** object as required by your application in the context file like this:

```
 const [headerData, setHeaderData] = useState({Menu: {PageUrl: ""}});
```

Both these methods will save your application from crashing and don't worry this is not a hack in React, it is just one of the correct ways to handle these types of issues.